# How can we handle major change/modification made in a CQ5 built website?

Tags: aem

I have already built a "website/Web application" in CQ5. And its structure under /apps is
/apps/videojet/components, /apps/videojet/templates etc. In short everything is under /apps/videojet/*

Now my boss has told me to rename the videojet folder to hiresite i.e /apps/hiresite/*

But if I do that I don't think any of my templates will points to components. As the Templates will still point to /apps/videojet/*.

**Now I have to change all my pages under /content that have cq:template as /apps/videojet/templates/xxx to  /apps/hiresite/templates/xxx.**

Also I am doing request.getDispatcher() in my Sling Serlvets and Dispatching to pages /content/videojet/xxx.

Even under /content it will be /content/hiresite/xxxx .

**How do I perform such a task?**

I don't think I can refractor like Eclipse can we ? Need Help I have too many pages, components and pages.
Do I have to do it manually?

Comment: why cant you refactor? looks like a simple search/replace in your .content.xml files.

Comment: @santiagozky : It's not a Maven Project, I built it using CRXDE Eclipse and CRXDELite. So I can't see content.xml

Comment: you can create a package of your /app/videojet and download it via the package manager, you can also use the vlt tool.

Answer (score 3):

[Groovy console](https://github.com/Citytechinc/cq-groovy-console) seems to be perfect tool here. You may easily write a simple script that iterates over the `/content` and changes property values from `/apps/videojet` to `/apps/hiresite`. You may also use [this one](https://gist.github.com/trekawek/715837940378d0bfe500). Paste the script to the Groovy console window and at the end add following line:

```
updateContent("/content", "/apps/videojet", "/apps/hiresite")
```

The first parameter is the root path, the second is the search subject and the third is the replacement string.

By default, the script will substitute the subject in all properties. You may override this behaviour passing fourth parameter - it should be a list of properties to examine:

```
updateContent("/content", "/apps/videojet", "/apps/hiresite",
    ["sling:resourceType", "sling:resourceSuperType"])
```

Comment: Agreed, but if you rename the folder below /apps you would also need to update the resourceTypes and resourceSuperTypes of each component. So I would recommend a custom script that takes care of each special case you might have or at least where you can also define which property to change.

Comment: @Thomas :: I was thinking of the same thing. I plan to creating a service that would to the refractor for me. But isn't this too much of an overhead? I don't think CQ5 was created by very smart people, other frameworks like Spring are well designed and have a lot of code manageability. Wish CQ5 were like that.

Comment: Scripts like this I usually do the quick and not clean way, e.g. just a jsp with the logic in it. So you can easily package it and don't have a bundle for a one time script.

Comment: I've added the fourth, optional parameter - it is a list of properties to substitute. The script can be invoked a few times, on different root paths, to update all required nodes.

Comment: Also, I'd strongly encourage to use Groovy console rather than creating JSP / Java classes to refactor the existing content.

Comment: @TomekRękawek : Well I have created a Service that does the refactoring. It travels recursively through all nodes and changes the properties like sling:resourceType, cq:template etc. Can Groovy do that for me ?

Comment: Yep, the answer contains a script that does exactly this thing.